# Read Encrypted sqlite3 database in java which is created and encrypted in mfc C++

Tags: java, encryption, mfc, sqlite

I am working on an application which has a database which stores the data of the user, but due to security reason we decided to encrypt the database. But in my (MFC)application I have launched a program of java(jar file launched form MFC application) which will upload a file on cloud and store the time of upload in database.

Before their was no encryption so all went smooth, but now the database is encrypted and my java application fails to read the database. In my java application am using External Jar file names `sqlite-jdbc-3.7.15-M1.jar` and have done the connection in the following way.

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:IDPWD.idp");

            System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
            DatabaseMetaData dbm = c.getMetaData();
            // check if "employee" table is there
            ResultSet tables = dbm.getTables(null, null, "FileDwnlTable", null);
            if (tables.next()) {
                c.setAutoCommit(false);
                stmt = c.createStatement();
                String sql = "UPDATE FileDwnlTable set DWNL_TIME = '"
                        + LocalSysTime + "' where ID=1;";
                System.out.println(sql);
                stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                c.commit();
                stmt.close();
                c.close();
```

Now how can I open/read the encrypted database. In C++, MFC I have provided key which can be used and open the database and do the DataBase operations the command used in c++ , mfc is

```
try{
        db->open(DB_NAME);
        TRACE(_T("database opened"));

        db->key((char*)csPassword.GetBuffer(), csPassword.GetLength());

    }catch(CppSQLite3Exception e){
        return NULL;
    }
```

by using this we open our encrypted database and then do the operation. So how can I do the same in my Java application? Also the key (SHA1 Key) can be passed to the jar file , so the only question remains how can I open the database in JAVA using this key and do the operation on the same database?

Comment: Are you using Sqlcipher?

Comment: No am not using SQLchiper